Upgrading Ubuntu install hung
Running Ubuntu 24.04 in WSL2.  I ran sudo apt-get update followed by sudo apt-get upgrade.  The upgrade hung on libc:amd64.  It would not respond to Ctrl+C, so I rebooted the entire computer.
After the reboot, I tried to run upgrade again.  It said to run sudo dpkg --configure -a.  That also is hanging on libc:amd64, but at least it responds to Ctrl+C.  At this point I have left it trying to Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.39-0ubuntu8.1) ... for over 9 hours.
How can I get this back to a working state?  I found something suggesting  sudo apt-get install -f, but that referred me back to the dpkg command that I have been trying.

SInce it is WSL, why not just remove the whole WSL and reinstall?

I don't want to lose anything in my /home/<username> directory.

Just make a backup of your home directory before reinstalling. And restore it later

What is the systemd version? And what is the output of cat /etc/wsl.conf?

There was a bug in systemd which triggered this https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1060387;msg=37 https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/11097
